# deleting out the grep search contents from a file in linux shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have been using grep command to search the contents from a file , 
Following is the command and its output:-

```
grep -i -A4 -B5 -w  "servername.*xyz" httpd.conf.webserver.apache22.orig

<VirtualHost *>
ServerAdmin errorhelp@xyz.com
DocumentRoot "/opt/xyz/www"
DirectoryIndex  error.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html
ServerName email-xyz.com
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass / http://localhost/ui/pages/companies/xyz/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost/ui/pages/companies/xyz/
</VirtualHost>

--

<VirtualHost *>
ServerAdmin errorhelp@xyz.com
DocumentRoot "/opt/xyz/www"
DirectoryIndex  error.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html
ServerName xyz.p.com
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass / http://localhost/ui/pages/companies/xyz/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost/ui/pages/companies/xyz/
</VirtualHost>
```

Can someone please suggest me the ways for removing the abve two stanza's from a file permanently.

and Following are the approaches that i have tried, Can someone suggest me my mistake :-

```
sed -i "/`grep -i -A4 -B5 -w  "servername.*xyz" httpd.conf.webserver.apache22.orig`/d" httpd.conf.webserver.apache22.orig
```

where in backticks are not doing their job of executing the contents and passing it to the sed editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this gnu-awk with null `RS`:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -v IGNORECASE=1 '!/ServerName[[:space:]]+.*xyz/' httpd.conf.webserver.apache22.orig
```

`RS=` will make whole `<VirtualHost...</VirtualHost>` block in a single record and using `!/ServerName[[:space:]]+.*xyz/` we can negate the search results in output.

Comment: Hi Anubhava, Thanks its working fine but how to edit the current file i.e I just to remove the above two pasted stanza's from the file. The above two stanza's are extracted with the help of grep command and mine logic is to remove them up from the current file.

Comment: You can do: `awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -v IGNORECASE=1 '!/ServerName[[:space:]]+.*xyz/' httpd.conf.webserver.apache22.orig > _file.tmp && mv _file.tmp httpd.conf.webserver.apache22.orig`

Comment: Hi Anubhava, Can you please explain me  the split ups as in :-

Comment: as in awk -v -- stands for taking the value from the variable.
RS=  -v -- doesnt know's about the Record set Value What -v going to do??
and ORS='\n\n'  -v again have a doubt for the flag -v
and for whole Virtual host container , Do i need to assign the same to the variable.

Comment: `-v RS=` sets input record separator as NULL. `-v ORS='\n\n'` sets output record separator as 2 new lines. `-v IGNORECASE=1` enables ignore case matching in awk command.